# Hadoop configure cluter queried based on a flag/env parameter

Tags: hadoop, mapr, ezmeral

Apologies beforehand if this turns out to be a silly question, I am new to hadoop environment.

I have two hadoop clusters **my-prod-cluster** and **my-bcp-cluster**.
Both are accessible over the same network.

Is there any way to configure my clusters in such a way that when I am in BCP mode, all my queries to `my-prod-cluster` gets routed to `my-bcp-cluster` (on the basis of some config parameter or environment variable)

So when flag=prod

`hadoop fs -ls /my-prod-cluster/mydir`   translates to `hadoop fs -ls /my-prod-cluster/mydir`

and fetches the data in /my-prod-cluster/mydir

when the flag=bcp

`hadoop fs -ls /my-prod-cluster/mydir`   translates to `hadoop fs -ls /my-bcp-cluster/mydir`

and fetches data from /my-bcp-cluster/mydir

I am using [mapr][1] flavour of haddop(provided by HP), version 6.1, in case that matters

Answer (score 1):

You could easily make a shell wrapper script that prepends the NameNode address to each query

For example, a fully-qualified command would look like this

```
hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://my-prod-cluster.domain.com/path/to/mydir
```

So, refactoring that, you could have a script like

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 -eq "prod" ]; then
  NAMENODE=hdfs://my-prod-cluster.domain.com
fi
# TODO: error handling and more clusters

PATH=$2
hdfs dfs -ls "${NAMENODE}${PATH}"
```

Then execute something like `my-hdfs-ls prod /mydir`

---

If you need something more complex than that like Kerberos tickets, and such, then creating a separate `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variable with unique `core-site` and `hdfs-site` XMLs for each cluster would be recommended.